# Array com tamanho definido por variável

Tags: c, array, variáveis

Verifiquei e não vejo erros.

```
void exibe (int * , int);

int main(){

  int n;
  int m[n], i;

  printf("Digite o numero de elementos do array : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("Digite o %d numero : ",i + 1);
    scanf("%d",&m[i]);
   }

  exibe(m,n);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void exibe (int *m, int n){
   int i;

   for (i = 0, i < n; i++)
    printf("Numero %d = %d \n",m[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado? Ocorre alguma mensagem de erro ou algo do gênero?

Comment: Aparece expected ; before ')' token

Comment: o comando for está errado, deve usar `; ` on tem uma vírgula: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem erros de digitação como `,` no lugar de `;`, falta colocar dois dados em um gabarito de texto para imprimir que espera dois dados diferentes e o maior problema é que está tentando criar um *array* com um dado que não existe ainda (até existe mas é algo pego quase aleatoriamente na memória), que normalmente acontece com essa ideia errada que as pessoa aprendem que tem que declarar todas variáveis antes de começar o código, o que impediria esse padrão de código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void exibe (int *m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("Numero %d = %d \n", i, m[i]);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Digite o numero de elementos do array : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int m[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Digite o %d numero : ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &m[i]);
    }
    exibe(m, n);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RRYa7K). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yimzdilm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Dynamic.c).

Isso tem lá seu risco mas nada crítico para um exercício, se alguém colocar um número muito grande, maior do que a capacidade da pilha dá erro, então o número deveria ser validado antes.

Comment: Conseguir descobrir as partes que eu errei, agora o código está funcionando. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: @MatheusSantos você sabe que pode votar em tudo no site também?

Comment: Sim, vou votar em outras postagens também.

Comment: @MatheusSantos você pode votar nessa pra começar. Voto é diferente de aceitação.